# Druid - No space left on device (Middle Manager)

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, memory-management, druid

[Druid](http://druid.io/) cluster with 2 nodes, 1 Node with broker service and other node executing remaining 4 druid services (Coordinator, Overload, Historical, MiddleManager). EC2 machine type is t2.xlarge.

My target of ingestion data into Druid is 150 million records in 1 data source, to test Druid`s capability on consumption to response in Sub Seconds.

**Problem**

I have loaded 10M of records into Druids data source. After this benchmark, I am facing **Java.io.IOException: No Space Left on device** due to middle manager services. Can anyone guide me with suitable configurations to load data in this huge chunk.

I have tried following options as Hit & Try strategy:

- Increased JVM memory of middle manager & historical services
- Increased buffer size of historical node upto 300 GB
- Reboot EC2 machine and restarted running services

[image]

Comment: Share your current config for jvm middlemanagers and the ingestion task, Whats the duration of segments?

Comment: @mdeora
Historical Node JVM
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1280m

MiddleManager:
-Xms64m
-Xmx64m

I have reduced no of threads for middlemanager from 27 to 9 to due to high buffer size and avoiding buffer memory errors while ingestion

Comment: What is the segment granularity?

Comment: Segment granularity is "DAY" as i am loading 30 days of data and target partition size is 5000000. Datasource is containing 54 columns.

Comment: What is the total file size of the data of 30 days?

Comment: File size is 241 mb and record count in file is 1 million.

Comment: @mdeora 
Let me share my current progress on this issue,

On recommended EC2 r5.2xlarge I have executed historical and middle manager nodes. This machine having more than 64 gb RAM and 8 vCPU. 
Running Druid cluster with default configurations except buffer size for thread (half of default value). Storage configured to AWS S3. Segment granularity set by "day". 

Above setup of druid cluster was successful till 17 millions of records in ingestion process. After that still facing the same issue. Not able to ingest further data.

Comment: If you could colate this info in your question itself, it would be helpful. Also possibly include, below historical - 

#threads and buffers
druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes
druid.processing.numThreads

#segment storage
druid.segmentCache.locations
druid.server.maxSize


middlemanager - 

druid.worker.capacity
druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes
druid.processing.numThreads
druid.indexer.task.defaultRowFlushBoundary

Answer (score 2):

Please check the tmp dir settings in the following configurations.

grep -r "var" conf/druid/cluster/data

conf/druid/cluster/data/middleManager/jvm.config:-Djava.io.tmpdir=var/tmp
conf/druid/cluster/data/middleManager/runtime.properties:druid.indexer.task.baseTaskDir=var/druid/task
conf/druid/cluster/data/historical/jvm.config:-Djava.io.tmpdir=var/tmp
conf/druid/cluster/data/historical/runtime.properties:druid.processing.tmpDir=var/druid/processing
conf/druid/cluster/data/historical/runtime.properties:druid.segmentCache.locations=[{"path":"var/druid/segment-cache","maxSize":300000000000}]

In my case, the var folder locates in a small volume (You may use "df -h" to check it. ), I have to updated it to /data/var which has much more space.

Hope it would help a bit.